# Android: Will static variable always available as long as the application still running

Tags: android, android-activity, static-variables

I understand that if I have an instance variable in an activity. Data will be gone if the activity gets killed by the OS to free memory. When does the static variable get destroy. Will the OS kill the application to free memory if application gone to background.

I have an application with a static variable which hosted whole application data. Do I need to save / restore it and where should I do it?

Comment: You can use shared preferences to save non-sensitive data. It will outlive the application's life-cycle, which means it will be stored even if the app is closed

Comment: In activity, there is onPause , onDestroy. How do I check the application as a whole.

Comment: Load data onCreate, and save as soon as changes are made

Answer (score 1):

> Will the OS kill the application to free memory if application gone to background.

Not immediately. But, when your app is in the background, [its process can be terminated at any point](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

> Do I need to save / restore it

Yes.

> where should I do it?

Generally speaking, you persist the data when it changes. Treat your static fields as a cache, nothing more.